What is smallest hole water will flow through a rain gutter cover?
Consider cover installation over rain gutters on a home.
Reading this question and answer, referenced in link on this site, is very interesting:
Maximum hole size to stop a fluid passing through a solid.
However, in the example above, it appears to have a stack or vertical amount of water.
If water is free flowing over a metal surface, perforated with $0.045\, ''$ holes, will water actually flow through, or will the surface tension, or other physics of water, simply cause the water to flow in a uniform body of flowage right over the holes, thereby not actually going through the $0.045\, ''$ holes or getting into the rain gutter?
Here you can see the gutter with $0.045\, ''$ holes.
Geographic location: NE Wisconsin, USA. (In case this influences surface tension or flow of water.)
Thanks,
curious Physics and Engineering reader... and homeowner.

Maybe I'm missing something, but if you install channels with holes in over your gutters, won't the channels get clogged by debris just as quickly as your uncovered gutters would have done ?

The link shows gutter covers, not gutters. They fit on top of gutters. Needles stay on the cover. Water drops through to the gutter and drains away. The gutters don't get filled with wet debris that mildews. The debris on top dries out. Debris that would fill the gutter forms a pile that topples over and falls off. So less debris on the roof. It is meant for needles. Probably because flat leaves would cover all the holes and prevent water from dropping through.

Of course some water will go through, but with such small holes, some water will flow sideways on top without going through, especially during heavy rain. If you want to eliminate water flowing sideways, the cover should have some protrusions/walls on the side, channeling the flow and making the water column taller, so more water goes through the holes. To curb the amount of needles going into the gutter, maybe use two or more covers on top of each other.

Thank you for your feedback. The comments correctly identify the reason these gutter covers are being considered is to prevent pine needles from clogging up rain gutters. As I understand the comments posted, the water will still go through the small 0.045” holes. Understanding that a heavy rain or where leaves cover it, the water will run off the side. Thanks
